# Anaconda3 install PATH issue

Tags: python, ubuntu, path, anaconda

ISSUE FIXED: Restart fixed the issue.

I've just finished installing Anaconda3 on Ubuntu 16.04. It automatically added the following line to .bashrc.

> export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

However when I run python I still get the default python 2 version.

> printenv PATH

gives me

> /home/username/anaconda/bin:/home/username/bin: ...

What is causing the 3 to be dropped from the path?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue with a simple restart. Still not sure where the original PATH without the 3 in it came from as I hadn't restarted before.